# Emit property to set a dictionary value

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

I try to emit a set field method for a property in a dynamic assembly.

The C# code wanted is :

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, object> propertyBag = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public string PropertyName
{
    set { propertyBag["PropertyName"] = value; }
}
```

PropertyName and its type must be dynamic

My code to emit the setter is:

```
PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("propertyBag", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), FieldAttributes.Private);

MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new[] { propertyType });
ILGenerator setIL = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, fieldBuilder.FieldType.GetMethod("set_Item", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) }));
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);
```

When running the code which set the property, i have an

> **AccessViolationException**: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

An idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter order of `set_item` seems to be off.

Have a look at this decompiled example, `value` (arg1) should be the second parameter, not the first:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldfld class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, object> C::propertyBag
IL_0006: ldstr "PropertyName"
IL_000b: ldarg.1
IL_000c: callvirt instance void class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, object>::set_Item(!0, !1)
IL_0011: ret
```

Taken from here:
[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgBgAJDSUBuKqwgZgeLoGE6A3lToi6AByjYAbgEMMMOrBkATCADtcATzoARbGAzZ1MqJoA8jGmjoRgAKxgGAfOKgQxMKBk0AhGQHM6AF46NRgAd119Q2NTC1IrG3tHDCcACgBKVkphUU4GBLoABTcPL00AORkAWxhckSFKUWa6AGcYDEFXd09vP38AbQAiEp7yqtqhgF1gullcAFcYZjoAX3q1qlWgA==)